# Nginx common configuration that I might have missed

Tags: centos, nginx, django

I recently moved from Apache Mod_wsgi to Nginx, and I have seen a major improvement on speed a lowering on memory usage and I am generally very happy with the it.

I am not a server expert, so please be gentle.

I am wondering if there are any small configuration that I might have missed, that will cause me some issues in the long run...

Please see my **nginx.conf** file

```
user  nginx nginx;

worker_processes  4;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log info;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    include         /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;

    log_format main
            '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
            '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
            '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
            '"$gzip_ratio"';

    client_header_timeout   10m;
    client_body_timeout     10m;
    send_timeout            10m;

    connection_pool_size            256;
    client_header_buffer_size       1k;
    large_client_header_buffers     4 2k;
    request_pool_size               4k;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers    4 8k;
    gzip_types      text/plain;

    output_buffers  1 32k;
    postpone_output 1460;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;
    tcp_nodelay     on;

    keepalive_timeout       75 20;

    ignore_invalid_headers  on;
    index index.html;

    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name localhost;
            location /media/  {
                    root /www/django_test1/myapp; # Notice this is the /media folder that we create above
            }
            location /mediaadmin/  {
                    alias /opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/; # Notice this is the /media folder that we create above
            }
            location / {
                    # host and port to fastcgi server
                    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
                    fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
                    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
                    fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
                    fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
                    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
                    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
                    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
                    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
                    fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
                    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
                    client_max_body_size 100M;
                    }
            access_log      /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log main;
            error_log       /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log;
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick Google search: http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration#Full_examples http://brainspl.at/nginx.conf.txt and many more.

Comment: And any more context? Will this be running on your laptop or a 32 core server? How many hits are you expecting? How much bandwidth? Do you have/need failover/redundancy? Is the server doing anything else?

Comment: You probably want to specify a root directive outside of the location blocks, within your server block. Especially for FastCGI, this is a common cause of scripts not being found by the server. Also, server_name localhost is a bit unusual, but I presume it is for a test server.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to set lower keepalive timeout, 75 is too much and practically useless. I usually use 10-20 seconds, that should be enough. But if you don't expect a lot of requests, 75 is okay too.